# CodeIgniter with PHP Access Forbidden (Windows 10)

Tags: php, codeigniter, xampp

I am working on a PHP project on the localhost using CodeIgniter/XAMPP and have encountered this as soon as I try get into one of my controllers.

[image: Error Image]

I have worked on other computers and have had no problems like this.

Answer (score 1):

The issue appears to be with your permissions. You need to change the permssions of the '/var/www' on Apache2 or if you're using Apache change the permission of 'Htdocs'.

Comment: `/var/www`? On Windows 10?

Comment: Under your c drive go to xammp and then change your permissions on the htdocs folder ie take ownership of the folder

Comment: I left that there for Linux users.